# Translation function for multi language website

Tags: php

I have write a function for translation website but it's not working fine. getting only 1 value from language file here is the function

```
function translate($key) {
    $language = isset($_SESSION['language']) ? $_SESSION['language'] : 'en'; // Default language if not set
    $translationFile = 'languages/' . $language . '.php';

    if (file_exists($translationFile)) {
        $translations = require_once $translationFile;
        if (isset($translations[$key])) {
            return $translations[$key];
        } else {
            echo "Translation not found for key: " . $key;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Language file not found: " . $translationFile;
    }

    return ''; // Return empty string if translation not found
}
```

Here is the `en.php` file code

```
return [
    'arabic' => 'Arabic',
    'nepali' => 'Nepali',
    'english' => 'English',
    'welcome_message' => 'Welcome to our website!',
    'about' => 'About',
    'services' => 'Services',
    'contact' => 'Contact',
    'dashboard' => 'Dashboard',
    'dashboard_page' => 'Dashboard page',
    'hello' => 'Hello',
    // Add more translation key-value pairs as needed
];
```

[image: What I get in frontend]

Comment: `require_once` returns `true` or `false`

Comment: @brombeer not if the required file itself returns something. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-141 (require and include behave identical, apart from how they handle errors.)

Comment: Ture, Also I have checked with var_dump($translations) in return getting all records but still not getting others values

Comment: Using `require_once` is the problem. PHP will only include the file the first time you call this function. This needs to be `require`, so that it happens every time you call the function.

Comment: But it would make more sense to re-design the code so it doesn't rely on repeatedly requiring files. Instead, make it more function-based.

Comment: @ADyson Can you Please write me any example.

Comment: An example of how to use a function?? I mean, you'd have a function, pass it the required language as a parameter, and then it returns the correct data (which you can store in a data file, or a database, or wherever you like, so that it's editable independent of the actual code. e.g. you could store it as JSON format in a file and then the PHP would read that data, json_decode it, and return it)